# Using S3 and java how to approach writing junit test for the fileUpload method below

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, junit

uploading to amazon S3 which is making it confusing on how to Mock the upload

```
@Service
    public class S3service {
        private AmazonS3 s3client;
        @Value("test")
        private String bucketName;
        private String folder = "test";
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @PostConstruct
        private void intitialAmazon() {
            this.s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
        }
```

Method wanting to unit test. Taking in a byte array

```
    public String uploadFile(byte[] pdf) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdf);
        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, folder + "/" + "pdf", inputStream, new ObjectMetadata()));
        return "Uploaded";
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here, are you trying to mock when uploadFile(...) is called whether s3client.putObject(...) is called or actually trying to test the upload functionality itself?, if it's the latter then it would be an integration test. If it's the first one, then create a mock object for AmazonS3 and making sure putObject is called when uploadFile(...) is called will be your test. In unit test, we should only be looking to test the method, dependencies should be mocked, here functionality of putObject(...) is a dependent.

Comment: If you have docker running you can deploy [localstack](https://localstack.cloud) into it which provides many mock but functionally equivalent AWS services. I just started using it for function tests in my build and it’s awesome.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. If you need to mock s3Client, you can use PowerMockito or just Mockito with java reflection for setting the mock to the private field.